# Call a function in a sibling MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

On my stage is a MovieClip called Box and a MovieClip called InfoBox.  InfoBox has a function called setInfo.  Box, when clicked (It is a MovieClip, not a button), wants to call the setInfo function of InfoBox.

I tried using the following code in Box:

```
MovieClip(this.parent).InfoBox.setInfo();
```

This produced the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@34a8ef99 to flash.display.MovieClip.
at Box/infoBox()
```

What is proper way to call a function in a sibling MovieClip?

Edit
InfoBox.as looks like this:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class InfoBox extends MovieClip {

        public function InfoBox() {
            //Constructor
        }

        public function setInfo(){
            trace("info set");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you add the children to the stage? can you post your code?

Comment: I added InfoBox manually in flash editor.  Box is added from another script using `stage.addChildAt(box,0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a name to `InfoBox`. Then you can access it like this:

```
var b:InfoBox = this.parent.getChildByName(“InfoBox”) as InfoBox;
b.setInfo();
```

Comment: `1061: Call to a possibly undefined method setInfo through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.`

Comment: Try with the new code. If it doesn't work, then I think `InfoBox` doesn't have a method `setInfo()`. Are you sure it does? Also, are you sure you use the correct name?

Comment: Maybe I messed up InfoBox.  I pasted the code into my original post.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT call a function on a sibling clip.  Instead, dispatch an event from the child Class that wants to request the function call, have the parent listen for it, and then have the parent call the appropriate function. This is known as "loose coupling", and will serve you well in the long haul.

Comment: Is there a specific benefit to loose coupling?

Comment: Yes. It means that you can replace the component with anything that dispatches that same event, and it will still work. Or you could replace the other component with something else (or have something completely different happen in response to that event without altering that clip/Class).

Comment: To give you an example: I work for a company that is still stuck in AS2. Every time we go from an audio version of one of our products to a text only version, we repeat the same work, because the next button knows about how the parts with the instructions are built, and so it's not possible to replace it wholesale. Instead, you have to go in and edit each frame of the instructions. I spent about 8 hours over the weekend prototyping a set of Classes that would let you switch from audio to text only in about 5 minutes instead of 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

from the child clip you can do this:

```
(parent as MovieClip).InfoBox.setInfo();
```

Comment: That won't work because we see in the error message that parent is a Stage. So `(parent as MovieClip)` return `null`. Also I doubt `InfoBox` is a property of the stage.

Comment: That causes this error:

    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Box/infoBox()

Answer (score 0):

The name for the class is InfoBox, but you need to use the name for that specific instance of the class. When you place a movieclip manually in the Flash editor you can give it a name in the Properties window.